# TYPO3 multiple Domains causing preview error

Tags: typo3, preview, tt-news

The following domains are set up:

[image]

Now, when I edit a tt_news entry and click the save-and-preview icon, the domain looks like this:

```
http://www.eyec-inspection.com/http://www.eyec-inspection.com/news-events/ar... etc
```

The system uses the first domain to open the link, so when I move www.eyec.de to the top, the link changes accordingly.

I've read in a forum that this is supposed to be standard behaviour, but highly doubt that.

Is there anyone experiencing a similar issue or knows a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you entered the protocol into the domain record. You must only enter the domain (without `http://` or `https://`) into the domain record.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the issue here. There's only a protocol entered for the domains without www at the beginning. They redirect to www.domain.tld, which is set as baseUrl then.